# How to pass a message in view result object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Upon failed authorization, I am redirecting the user back to the login page, that works but also I want to pass a message along with it.

I am extending AuthorizeAttribute class and overriding a method.

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml" };           
        }
    }
```

then using CustomeAuthorize where I want to give access to authorized roles.

I tried passing message but doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried using the viewbag? That should work, you can store you custom message there and display it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `ViewBag`:

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml" };     
ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Not authorized";
```

In the redirected view, call the below:

```
@ViewBag.ErrorMsg;
```

Or you can create a model to render that error message as follows:

```
public class Render {
    public string Msg { get; set;}
}
```

In the controller:

```
aRender.Msg = "Not authorized"; //aRender is an object here
```

Similarly call it in the view:

```
@model YourProjectNameSpace.YourModel

 @Model.Msg;
```

Comment: but it doesn't change the url after returning viewresult